# Converting "From-To" matrix (wide format) to long format in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am importing a csv  matrix (non spatial table)

```
        |ALLIER |AISNE |ALPES
|ALLIER | -     |10    |200
|AISNE  |70     | -    |100
|ALPES  |10     |100   |-
```

What I want using Qgis

```
|FROM   |TO     |VALUE
|ALLIER |AISNE  |10
|ALLIER |ALPES  |200
|AISNE  |ALLIER |70
|AISNE  |ALPES  |100
....
```

My real data displayed in LibreOffice Calc (my matrix is  100 x 100)

[image: example]

Comment: Perhaps this is something better asked on another forum - however, you should simply use an application like LibreOffice Calc (spreadsheet) to pivot the data and re-load it into QGIS from the pivot table instead.

Comment: How have you imported that into QGIS? As a non-spatial table?

Comment: Yes non spatial table